# No logro guardar las fotos que tomo

Tags: android, android-studio, vscode, android-layout

al sacar fotos no me las esta guardando donde dice....ahi estoy generando el nombre y ubicacion...

```
     file = null;
                //folder = new File(folderName);
                folder  =  getExternalFilesDir(null);
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
                file = new File(folderName, "/" + imageFileName);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }

                ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                        Image image = null;
                        try {
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                            buffer.get(bytes);
                            save(bytes);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (image != null) {
                                image.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

y con este metodo estoy guardando las fotos pero no pasa nada, supuestamente ya con eso y llamandolo deveria estar guardando las fotos para poder rescatarlas

```
 private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            try (OutputStream output = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath())) {
                                //output = new FileOutputStream(archivar);
                                output.write(bytes);

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

y este es el motodo para abiri la galeria y ver las fotos pero se ve en blanco, este ya esta en otra clase.

```
    public void getFromSdCard(){
        /*File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Dcim/Camara" );*/
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(folderName),"/");
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++){
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

ya tengo los permisos y todo, me eh fijado en el Gradle y todo ok, realmente no se que podria ser ya que tengo vallidado que si no tengo los permisos no pueda avanzar en ciertos procesos..

Actualizacion de la consulta

```
  public void getFromSdCard(){
        /*File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Dcim/Camara" );*/
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"/");
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++){
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

asi quedo el getFromSdCard y el save...

```
private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            OutputStream output = null;
                            try {
                                output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                //output = new FileOutputStream(archivar);
                                output.write(bytes);

                            }finally{
                                if (null!= output){
                                    output.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

ahora me dice que la variable myBitmal viene vacia....

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem (@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position){
        //iflating the item.xml
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, container,false);

        //referenciando la vista de imagen desde el archivo item.xml
        //AppCompatImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);
        ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);

        //establecer la imagen en el imageView

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePaths.get(position));
        if (myBitmap != null){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0,0,myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "myBitmap == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Añadir la vista
        Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object){
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

segun yo aun no estoy guardando la imagen bien pero ya no se bien donde ni como hacerlo

Actualizacion N°2 del problema, lo que actualmente sucede es que no puedo ver el contenido de la carpeta contenedora ya que esta vacia...

```
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                        //este código se utiliza para procesar las imágenes capturadas y guardarlas
                        // en la memoria externa del dispositivo
                        Image image = null;
                        try {
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                            buffer.get(bytes);
                            save(bytes);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (image != null) {
                                image.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                        OutputStream output = null;
                        try {
                            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            output.write(bytes);
                        } finally {
                            if (null != output) {
                                output.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

me asegure de que las rutas sean las mismas pero aun asi no se ma podido ver el contenido....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se supone que inicialmente estás guardando tu archivo usando `getExternalFilesDir(null)` que guardaría tu archivo en :

> `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/`

pero en la función getFromSdCard() estás usando `getExternalFilesDir(folderName)` cuando debería ser también `getExternalFilesDir(null)`.

Recuerda que si defines un valor diferente a null, debe ser el "tipo" de directorio de archivos a devolver. Puede ser nulo para la raíz del directorio de archivos o una de las siguientes constantes para un subdirectorio:

> Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS,
> Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS,
> Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES o
> Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES.

Comment: lo editare y vere que paso ya que ahora me dice que mi variable de imagen viene vacia :c

Comment: Ok, ahora esta correcta la ruta, ahora revisa la ruta en tu función save() ahí también tienes otra ruta.

Comment: Si, null en todas , para que de esta forma se guarde y se obtenga la imagen de la misma ubicacion, en este caso: /<Package Name>/files/

Comment: en el save no me deja colocar null si no "(String) null" pero se termina callendo la app

Comment: No, dentro de save() debes asegurar que la variable "file" se obtiene de esta forma   File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"/" + nombrearchivo);

Comment: cambiare todo y te estare avisando :D

Comment: me sirvio y no, aun tengo el mismo problema que al parecer en el metodo getFromSdCard() no funciona bien y el tema es que la lista esta vacia por es no tiene nada que mostrar, "File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/");" esa variable es la que esta vacia pero no se como hacer para que tenga datos ya que me asegure que el directorio sea el mismo en todos lados....

Comment: @FELIPEEDUARDOROJAS está iterando el directorio, pero me parece que no realiza nada, no se que trates de realizar aquí, si deseas obtener la instancia de File del archivo deberías aquí definir el nombre:  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"/" + nombreArchivo);